# Construct Curvilinear Coordinates from "Tangent Basis Field"

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Let say that you are on a open, simple connected subset of the Euclidian plane (2 dimensional) and you have a second order tensor field defined over it. At every point we have a second order tensor which is real, positive, and symmetric, thus it has at every point two eigenvectors which are orthogonal. So in some sense this defines at every point a tangent basis. If the tensor field is smooth, then the variation of this basis from point to point is also smooth. Let us suppose that is as smooth as we may need. My question is the following:
Can I construct some curvilinear coordinates that has these eigenvectors as basis in their tangent space? If it can be done, under what other assumptions or conditions?
If it can only be done locally, then it is good enough.

Comment: Set $E_1,E_2$ to be your eigenvectors. Are you asking if there are local coordinates $x_1,x_2$ such that $E_i = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$, i=1,2  ?

Comment: Exactly this idea is used in geometry processing for remeshing. I googled this article which looks like good starting point http://geometry.caltech.edu/pubs/ACDLD03.pdf

Comment: And one more thing. Eigen vectors do not have to be continuous when the tensor field is continuous. I once had such a question and found counterexample http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318521/continuous-eigen-value-decomposition

Comment: Modulo clarification in response to Holonomia's comment, it appears you're looking for the [Frobenius theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_%28differential_topology%29), and the answer to your question is "yes".

Comment: @tom That counterexample concerns continuity but not smoothness.